# Show $\det e^A=e^{tr A}$ using Abel's identity

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, determinant

I want to prove $$\det e^A=e^{tr A},$$ $tr A$ being the trace of a square matrix $A$ using Abel's identity $$W(t)=e^{\int_{t_0}^{t} tr A ds} W(0).$$ Since $e^{At}$ is the special fundamental matrix solving the ODE system $x'=Ax$ and is the identity matrix when t=0, $W(t)=e^{tr At}$. I therefore get $$\det e^{At}=e^{tr At}.$$ Can I then conclude that $e^A=\det A$?

Comment: You're asking if you can set $t=1$ in an equation?